# Save directory tree to CSV, along with whether element is a file or folder in powershell

Tags: powershell, tree

So far I've got this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'C:\MyFolder' | 
Select-Object FullName, name | 
Export-Csv -path 'C:\output.csv' -noTypeInfo
```

It gives me a CSV with the full path name, and name of each folder & file in a directory.

However, I'd like a 3rd column that has either 'Folder' or 'File' (or something similar). Basically just a column that explicitly tells me whether something is a file or folder.

I feel like it should be a simple case of adding a new column like `FullName, name, Type` - but not sure what options are available.

Is this possible?

Comment: `Select-Object FullName, Name, Attributes`

Comment: Thanks. Think that works. So does "Archive" mean file, as part of the output?

Comment: Ideally I'd like it just to show one option per row (directory or file).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Attributes` property however, this might give you more information than you really need, see [`FileAttributes` Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-6.0#fields).

If you simply need a property with 2 values (`File` or `Directory`) you can use the boolean property `PSIsContainer` as reference to construct your new [*calculated property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11-create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'C:\MyFolder' | 
    Select-Object FullName, Name, @{N='Type';E={('File', 'Directory')[$_.PSIsContainer]}} |
    Export-Csv -path 'C:\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll test this out tomorrow when I'm back online.